# Is $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0}f(-k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k)$ always?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I wonder, whether it is always the case

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0}f(-k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k)$$

in regards of summation methods for divergent series?

Comment: One sum is $f(0)+f(-1)+f(-2)+...$ and the other $f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+...$. What are you really trying to ask?

Comment: For the corrected statement, yes. This is making the change of variable $k=-n$ to get $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(-k)=\sum_{n=0}^{-\infty}f(n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{0}f(n)$.

Comment: Just to keep the discussion next to the question: A summation method inputs a sequence of numbers and returns a number that one calls "the sum" of the sequence. The symbol $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(-k)$ is used to represent the sum of the sequence $\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ given by $k\mapsto f(-k)$. The symbol $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0}f(k)$, unless specified otherwise, is used to represent the sum of the same sequence, the same. Then any summation method will assign the same sum.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another "no".

One can work with "bilateral" summation methods for divergent series of the form
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k
$$
There is no reason such a method should be "symmetric" in the sense of your question.  Nor, more generally, need the sums assigned to
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_{-k}
$$
be the same.  Some bilateral methods are symmetric, of course, but others are not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As for the proof, it's quite simple.

$s_n=f(0)+f(1)+\ldots+f(n)$

$s_{-n}=f(0)+f(-(-1))+f(-(-2))+\ldots+f(-(-n))=f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+\ldots+f(n)$

That is, $s_n=s_{-n}$

As $n\to-\infty$, so $-n\to+\infty$. That is, both series converge or diverge together and to the same value.

However, take note of how I defined the infinite series on the left, making both series analagous. Ask if you have any question.

Comment: It this true for all summation techniques used for divergent series?

Comment: @Anixx They are just two symbols to denote the same sequence of numbers to be added. The sum of any summation method depends only on the sequence of numbers to be added.

Comment: @Alamos divergent series depend on the order

Comment: @Anixx When I said "the same sequence" I really meant the same sequence, order and all. The two symbols represent the sum of the same sequence. Or do you want somehow the first symbol to represent the sum of the (non-sequence) $\{...,-2,-1,0\}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ given by $n\mapsto a_n$?

Comment: @Alamos the first symbol definitely represents $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^0f(k)$

Comment: @Anixx Yes, then the two symbols are definitely representing the sum of the same sequence, same order and all. Therefore, any summation method should assign the same sum.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example if $f(k):=e^k$, then one of the sums converges, the other diverges.

Comment: I made a typo in the question, sorry.